# How to minimize transaction log sqlserver database .?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have database size is more than 125 GB . and every 1 hour the database is not respond . the message is every time say (The transaction log for database MESP_2015 is full) .
i make some solutions but the problem is still .

1. I change hard drive to 1 TB .
2. I set the backup every day one time automatically .
3. I tried (SHRINKFILE) and recovery (log file and database). using sql command
4. I add More log files to ease pressure on databases.

All this idea is not help me .

Can I Remove transaction and rebuild again or remove log file . see screen shot .

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [al-mnar.com](https://www.al-mnar.com/images/Untitled2.png))</sub>

Comment: Why are your data files named “log” and have `.ldf` file extensions? I’m actually curious how your database has multiple `PRIMARY` mdf files... usually there’s only one.

Comment: The first file (mesp_2015) and (mesp_2015_log) is maket by system . other files i added by me .

Comment: That is such a confusing set up. LDF files, named log, that aren't log files, 2 log files that aren't the same size and have different size limits. Why? Also, shrinking your database file can have severe impacts on your indexes. Also, your primary files are less that 50MB, but your log is over 1000MB? Also, I *assume* you are so mg transaction log back ups, right....?

Comment: I know there is an error but how can I fix it ?

Comment: What kind of DML queries are running on the database? How much off-row storage is being used?

Comment: In addition to daily full database backups, schedule intra-day transaction log backups (e.g. every 15 minutes). This will keep the transaction log size reasonable and ensure you lose no more than 15 minutes of data in the event of an unplanned recovery. Most importantly, test your recovery plan (e,g, perform a test restore).